# How can I specify that a field of a table can have a value take only from a specific set of values?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms, ddl

I am not so into database and I have the following problem related the set of values that a field can be have. I am using **MySql**.

I have this **DDL** table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE actors (
  id        BigInt(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  sample_id VarChar(128) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  `role`    Char(2) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  wiews     VarChar(16) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci,
  pid       VarChar(16) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci,
  `name`    VarChar(128) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci,
  address   VarChar(128) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci,
  country   Char(3) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci, 
  PRIMARY KEY (
      id
  )
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
ALTER TABLE actors COMMENT = '';
ALTER TABLE actors ADD CONSTRAINT fk_actors_pgrfas FOREIGN KEY (sample_id)
  REFERENCES pgrfas (sample_id)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION 
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

**I can't change the type of these fields because are used by an application.**

Someone have provided me a specification that says that the **role** field (that have to be a **Char(2)**) can take only values in this set: **IN('pr','co','br')**.

How can I specify in the previous **DDL** statment that this field can have only one of these 3 values?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an ENUM

> An ENUM is a string object with a value chosen from a list of
>   permitted values that are enumerated explicitly in the column
>   specification at table creation time

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html

eg ...

```
    CREATE TABLE your_table  (
      col1  VARCHAR(40),
      role ENUM('pr','co','br')
  );
```

Comment: This is definitely the right solution, however the OP states that he cannot change the table definition.

Comment: then  the OP  could check  the insert / update server side  or by store procedure

Comment: However   Assigning an ENUM with  values as char of 2 don't change the data type used in others parts .. of application

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not provide check constraints.  Also, you would need to modify the table to make these an enum (which would otherwise be the best approach in MySQL for a handful of values).

But, you can do this with a foreign key reference.

```
create table Roles (
     RoleName char(2) primary key
);

insert into Roles (RoleName)
    values ('pr'), ('co'), ('br');

alter table actors add constraint fk_actors_roles
    foreign key (role) references Roles(RoleName);
```